# Trying to upload image from iPhone to server using ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I'm trying to use ASIFormDataRequest to send a photo image from my 
iPhone app to my server.

When I do so, the server sends back an error 
message saying, "must be an image file," implying that there is 
something wrong with the formatting of my image. (Of course, that 
might not be the problem...but it's a good place to start.) I know 
there's no "problem," per se, on the server, because a previous 
approach I used (non-ASIHTTPRequest-based) worked fine. 
Here's my iPhone code:

```
        ASIFormDataRequest* request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: 
[NSURL URLWithString:photoUploadURLString]]; 
        request.username = self.username; 
        request.password = self.password; 
        [request setPostValue:self.place.placeId forKey:@"place_id"]; 
        NSData* jpegImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photo, 
PHOTO_JPEG_QUALITY); 
        NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"snapshot_%@_ 
%d.jpg", self.place.placeId, rand()]; 
        [request setData:jpegImageData withFileName:filename 
andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"snapshot[image]"]; 
        request.uploadProgressDelegate = self.progressView; 
        [request startSynchronous];
```

Anyone see anything wrong with this? (I'm fairly new to this stuff, so 
there could be something obvious I'm missing.)

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever try addData instead of setData, It worked on my solution.

```
[request addData:jpegImageData withFileName: filename andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photos"];
```

Edit: By the way, which server side are you using ?

Your problem might be inside of the your key `forKey:@"snapshot[image]"]` try to dummy variable key like `forKey:@"mysnapshot"]`

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, fayasar—I'm actually at an entirely different company now, and I'm not sure how I ultimately fixed this problem! But the solutions you recommended: using addData, and using a key similar to snapshot[image], sounds right. Thanks for your help.